# tail stops displaying in case of a log rotation

Tags: server, logging, tail, logrotate

I have to tail the log of a server (servicemix) and the log rotation is enabled. As soon as the rotation happens, tail stops displaying. I did some investigations and it is a bug in Debian : [Debian Bug Report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=548439). The bug has been around for a long time ago. Does anyone knows if this bug in Ubuntu is to be fixed?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I don't have to mention that this bug is total hell! Every time I have the problem, I have to interrupt the command tail and re-execute the command!

Comment: It is true that I can disable the log rotation. But I would like this problem to be fixed...

Answer (score 2):

The [Gnu coreutils](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils) version of tail has the `--follow[={name|descriptor}]` parameter, which allows you to follow the file name rather than the descriptor. It continues to tail files even after they rotate or truncate. From the help output:

> With --follow (-f), tail defaults to following the file descriptor, which
>   means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed, tail will continue to track
>   its end.  This default behavior is not desirable when you really want to
>   track the actual name of the file, not the file descriptor (e.g., log
>   rotation).  Use --follow=name in that case.  That causes tail to track the
>   named file in a way that accommodates renaming, removal and creation.

I'm on Fedora, but I believe that you can install the Gnu coreutils on Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install coreutils
```

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the interruption and resumption of your tail command by adding the requisite commands to your `logrotate` configs.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Log_Rotation - in short, you will probably want to put the command in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, the system-wide crontab which handles rotation.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the bug report, you can bypass the malfunctioning `inotify` code with:

```
tail ---disable-inotify servicemix.log
```

It will then use an older polling behavior.

Comment: I have just tested the workaround and it does not avoid tail to block... :-(

Comment: I did a second check and it is indeed the case on ubuntu 12.04 and debian...tail not working... That is not acceptable...

Comment: @RudyVissers Have you filed a bug report with Ubuntu yet?

Comment: I understand that this is not acceptable for you, but it may be of nu use to complain here as `coreutuils` is from Debian. Since this problem is not localized to Ubuntu, it is best to ask at [unix.se].

Comment: You are right and I will do that as soon as I find some time.