# Why does tail -f stop following /var/log/syslog?

Tags: command-line, syslog, tail

Ubuntu 22.04.

I am following `/var/log/syslog` with the `tail -f` command. It's a connection via ssh. It will follow the output of syslog for a couple of days, then just stop updating. It just sits there. If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminal the tail command and re-issue it, it picks up with the latest results, ones later than the last results from the previous iteration of `tail -f`. IOW, it stops following. How can I get it to continue following syslog without having to terminate the command and re-issue it? Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `journalctl --follow` ?

Comment: @Raffa you got this :-) and yes it is due to logrotate, tail -f is not intended for long term usage.

Comment: Related: [tail stops displaying in case of a log rotation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202420/tail-stops-displaying-in-case-of-a-log-rotation) (although it looks like the [inotify bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=548439) has since been fixed)

Answer (score 5):

I would use:

```
journalctl --follow
```

instead ... But, for `tail`, you probably need `-F` and not `-f` like so:

```
tail -F /var/log/syslog
```

as `-F` will retry if the file is not accessible ...

From [`man tail`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/tail.1.html):

```
-F     same as --follow=name --retry
```

... and:

```
--retry
       keep trying to open a file if it is inaccessible
```

Comment: Duh, of course, it's logrotate that is breaking my simple -f. Thanks for the better ways, and by using "journalctl --follow" I am seeing a whole lot of brute force attempts to log in via ssh as root, so I'm taking action.